React Loader v6: how to prevent child loaders from loading?
I am using the similar setup:
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  return isAuthenticated() ? <Outlet /> :  <Navigate to="/auth/signin" />
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <PrivateRoutes />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loader: async () => {
          return { data:  await getSensitiveData() };
        },
        element: <SensitiveDataHome />,
        children: [
          {
             path: '',
             index: true,
             element: <SensitiveDataDeeplyNestedElement />
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]);

My problem is that sensitive data loader will get executed, however it will predictably throw 401, because use is not yet authenticated. My final goal is to show 3 nested routes only and execute corresponding loaders only when user is authenticated yet I need the index routes.

Route loaders are called when the route is being loaded, so if you don't want the loader to be called then don't allow access to the route yet. Can you [edit] to clarify the actual problem here? You need to conditionally call getSensitiveData on the PrivateRoutes layout route? What does isAuthenticated do? Can you include a more complete and accurate [mcve] of the code you are working with?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8pa9kf?file=src%2FApp.tsx if you navigate to the /profile route - the loader will be executed, while it's pointless as user is not authenticated. pretty much i'm looking for something similar to beforeLoad method of TenStack/Router lib.

That's exactly what RRD route loaders are/do, they are called before the route is loaded. It seems you already understand the problem and solution though, just check that authenticated value in the other loaders where you don't want to call extraneous functions when the user is not authenticated.

Well, i'm Ok with they being executed before the routes. I'm not OK that they run in parallel without control. Even if I do authentication checks in every nested route (which is a bummer on it's own) parallel loaders will execute redirects multiple times, which triggers revalidation and all other sorts of problems. I think I'l just move to fetch-on-render with react-router until i get more time to migrate to 10Stack
